# Javascript - Are these functions doing the same thing?

Tags: javascript, object

Are there any possibilities in which the output of the two functions would be different?

```
 var o1 = {x1:1,y1:2,z1:3};
 var o2 = {x2:4,y2:5,z2:6};

 function extend(o1,o2)
 {
   for(p in o2)
   {
      o1[p] = o2[p];   
   }    

   return o1;
 }

 function union(o1,o2)
 {
    return extend(extend({}, o1), o2);   
 }
```

Comment: @Juhana: There's something to be said for reasoning through a problem, even if it takes a beginner a couple hours.

Comment: ah... thank you sir but I'm already studying Javascript the Definitive Guide by David Flanagan.

Answer (score 4):

The return value is always different, although the content of the returned object is always the same.

Function `extend()` modifies the first object, `union()` returns a new object. In other words:

```
var o1 = {x1:1,y1:2,z1:3};
var o2 = {x2:4,y2:5,z2:6};

union( o1, o2 );  // both o1 and o2 are unchanged, function returns a new object
extend( o1, o2 ); // returns o1 which has now been changed
```

---

Actually because the union function extends an object and the extend function copies only properties the return values *can* be different:

```
var o1 = [ 1, 2 ];
var o2 = [ 3, 4 ];

union( o1, o2 );  // returns an object
extend( o1, o2 ); // returns an array
```

Although even in this case the keys and their values would be the same.

Comment: so, in theory, they are doing the same thing despite which objects I insert as parameters?

Comment: The distinction is very important to understand but yes, the contents of the returned object will be the same.